# Ng-fullcalendar with angular 7

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, angular7

We're working on migrating our application from angular 6 to 7 and we're using Ng-fullCalendar.

Our package.json file includes the following versions:

```
"fullcalendar": "3.6.1",
"ng-fullcalendar": "1.7.1"
```

When compiling our project, we're getting the following error:

```
ERROR in node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(6123,66): error TS2344: Type '"timeout" | "onreadystatechange" | "responseType" | "withCredentials" | "msCaching"' does not satisfy the constraint '"abort" | "open" | "timeout" | "response" | "getAllResponseHeaders" | "getResponseHeader" | "overrideMimeType" | "readyState" | "responseText" | "setRequestHeader" | "status" | ... 22 more ... | "dispatchEvent"'.
      Type '"msCaching"' is not assignable to type '"abort" | "open" | "timeout" | "response" | "getAllResponseHeaders" | "getResponseHeader" | "overrideMimeType" | "readyState" | "responseText" | "setRequestHeader" | "status" | ... 22 more ... | "dispatchEvent"'.
```

Is there any workaround to resolve this problem?

Comment: Try this working example with code:
https://therichpost.com/full-calendar-integration-in-angular-latest-versions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This issue is already fixed:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/28000

You just have to update your @types/jquery

```
npm update @types/jquery
```

Comment: The update did the trick. But be aware that npm really updates this package. I needed uninstall and install it manually to really get the current version of @types/jquery.

Answer (score 3):

Add @types/jquery dev dependency

```
npm install @types/jquery --save-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a trick but I struggle with that issue about a week until I have added this in the compilerOptions

> "skipLibCheck": true

in the tsconfig.app.json file and this error has gone